# JavaScript chrome automation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation

Im trying to create a shortcut on chrome by console but I do know anything about JS.
The shortcut receive the key then click in some coordinate.

What`s the problem with my code?

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e)
{
  console.log(e.which); // Retur the number of key code
  if (e.which === 67))
  {  
      document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the key?

Where are the values from x and y coming from?

Is your code reaching the `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();` line?

Comment: x and y are "undefined" you will need to get those values from somewhere. `console.log(e)` and look through for those values

Comment: I`ll change the x and y before run the code. The actual error is:
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Comment: `if (e.which === 67))` should be  `if (e.which === 67)`